# Java objects difference

Tags: java, object

What are the difference between those two lists?

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(2);

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(2);
```

Comment: One is a List and one is an ArrayList. List is an interface and ArrayList is an implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the two lists, each time you are creating an `ArrayList`.

The difference is that `ArrayList implements List`, which is an interface.

In your code you can swap out the actual implementation of the `List` at any time if you refer to the interface rather than the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The type of list2 is List, so you can more easily change the exact type (instead of using ArrayList) later. With list1, the type is explicitly ArrayList.

You should try to be more general whenever possible (use List) because this is more flexible.